# Java regex URL prefix removal

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a set of URLs. Some of them have a string `www` as substring and some of them haven't. I need to remove prefixes in each URL. 
I tried remove this prefixes using many variants of regexp:

```
newStr = str.replaceAll("http://|http://www.", "");
newStr = str.replaceAll("^http://|http://www.$", "");
newStr = str.replaceAll("http://|http://www.", "");
```

where `str` - is an inputted URL string, and `newStr` is the URL after replacement.
Each of these variants replaces only `http://` prefix, but `www.` remains in result. How I can change my regexp to remove `http://` string as well as `http://www.` string?

I know that I can use `replaceAll()` twice:

```
newStr = str.replaceAll("http://", "").replaceAll("www.", "");
```

But what should I do to remain **one** `replaceAll()` and edit **only** the regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newStr = str.replaceFirst("^(http://)?(www\\.)?", "");
```

please note that `.` in regex means anything so you need to escape it, or you will strip first 4 symbols from `wwwiscool.com` and you probably don't want that. And you probably want to replace only the first matching prefix.

Comment: for https and http "^(http[s]?://)?(www\\.)?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace`, for example :

```
String str = "http://www.google.com";
str.replace("http://","").replace("http:// www.","").replace("www.","");
```

For more information about [str.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: @Atuos That was just an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what regexp I should use to call the `replace()` method only **once**?

Answer (score 0):

// removing http
val withOutHttp=contentUrl!!.split("//")[1]

```
        // removing www.domain.com
        val splitUrl: MutableList<String> = withOutHttp.split("/").toMutableList()
        splitUrl.removeAt(0)    // removing the host

        // adding array to string
        contentUrl=splitUrl.joinToString("/")
```